# xamarin.essentials.geolocation returning null location

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin.android, geolocation, xamarin.essentials

I am implementing google map on my Xamarin android application. This  is the method I call in OnCreate() to get the current location.

```
public async Task<LatLng> getCurrentLocation()
        {
            var location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(new GeolocationRequest
            {
                DesiredAccuracy = GeolocationAccuracy.Medium,
                Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
            });
            if (location != null)
            {

                var location_current = new LatLng(location.Latitude, location.Longitude);
                return location_current;
                
            }
            return new LatLng(63, 42);
        }
```

Sometimes it returns the correct location, but some times it return null as it have never been called. What can be the problem?

I have tried:

1. debugging and make sure that this code is hitted every time even when it returns null.
2. Making sure that it is not the location permission problem as I have included all the relevant permissions in AndroidManifest.xml as well as in OnRequestPermissionResult() method

Comment: What is the `LatLng`?  Have you set the `Location Mode` with High accuracy in your device settings?

Comment: ```Android.Gms.Maps.Model.LatLng```

Comment: Have you set the Location Mode with High accuracy in your device settings? Which variable returne the null location? location_current?